# Getting the name of a state in its `onEnter` hook

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm building an application where I want to toggle a property in a service the moment a user enters and leaves a route. To do this I need to know about the state's name in the `onEnter` and `onExit` hooks. This is relatively easy for the `onExit` hook since I can just inject the `$state` service and read the name of the current state. But since the current state has not been set yet when the `onEnter` hook is called there is no way of knowing what the state we're transitioning to.

I still need to to have fine control over other parts of the state so I'd rather not have any for loops. I'm looking for a way to be able to pass the `onEnter` function to the state, whilst still retrieving the state's name inside of the function itself.

Here is the code I've written:

```
function onEnter($state, Steps) {
  var stateName = $state.current.name; // Not possible. The current state has not been set yet! 
  var step = Steps.getByStateName(stateName);

  step.activate();
}

function onExit($state, Steps) {
  var stateName = $state.current.name; // No problem. We know about the state. 
  var step = Steps.getByStateName(stateName);

  step.deactivate();
}

$stateProvider
  .state('step1', {
    url: '/step1',
    templateUrl: 'templates/step1.html',
    controller: 'StepOneController',
    onEnter: onEnter,
    onExit: onExit
  });
```

My solution I'm using for now is to use a factory to create context for the `onEnter` function passed to the state. This is far from ideal because I still need to pass the state's name to it.

Here is an example of said workaround:

```
function onEnterFactory(stateName) {
  return function onEnter(Steps) {
    var step = Steps.getByStateName(stateName);

    step.activate();
  }
}

$stateProvider
  .state('step1', {
    url: '/step1',
    templateUrl: 'templates/step1.html',
    controller: 'StepOneController',
    onEnter: onEnterFactory('step1')
  });
```

Comment: You already know the state, because you have the `.state('step1')`

Comment: @devqon I do in this example. I forgot to mention I want to make this re-usable since there are at least 10 steps. Also it's not very DRY to do so in general.

Comment: Then define the statename variable beforehand, and use it twice

Comment: @devqon That would only further complicate the code, and it would require me to make a factory for onEnter methods to pass the name down (which is what I am doing for now to mitigate the issue).

Comment: Whatever you are trying to do, it should probably either be done in a controller (where you can access `$state.current`) or on `$stateChangeSuccess`. It is confusing to me however that `onEnter ` does not already refer to the current state and this is something that perhaps should be raised with the ui router team.

Comment: Just use ***this***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use ***this*** in onEnter onExit hooks. onEnter is invoked by following command:

```
$injector.invoke(entering.self.onEnter, entering.self, entering.locals.globals);
```

The second paramater of `$injector.invoke` is the value of ***this*** for the function it calls. So your code should look as follows:

```
function onEnter(Steps) {
  var stateName = this.name; 
  var step = Steps.getByStateName(stateName);

  step.activate();
}

function onExit(Steps) {
  var stateName = this.name;
  var step = Steps.getByStateName(stateName);

  step.deactivate();
}

$stateProvider
  .state('step1', {
    url: '/step1',
    templateUrl: 'templates/step1.html',
    controller: 'StepOneController',
    onEnter: onEnter,
    onExit: onExit
  });
```

Here is a working example of accessing a state's name in the `onEnter` and `onExit` hooks:

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router'])

.config(function($stateProvider) {
  function onEnter() {
    console.log('Entering state', this.name);
  }

  function onExit() {
    console.log('Exiting state', this.name);
  }

  $stateProvider.state('state-1', {
    url: '/state-1',
    template: '<p>State 1</p>',
    onEnter: onEnter,
    onExit: onExit
  }).state('state-2', {
    url: '/state-2',
    template: '<p>State 2</p>',
    onEnter: onEnter,
    onExit: onExit
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.1/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <nav>
    <a ui-sref="state-1">State 1</a>
    <a ui-sref="state-2">State 2</a>
  </nav>

  <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If this works that would be the perfect answer. I'll assume the code you demonstrated here is accurate and works. If someone could verify that independently too that would be great. I'll mark it as the answer for now.

Comment: @JonKoops I've added fiddle to answer, so you can check by self.

Comment: That looks great, I fixed some minor grammar issues in your answer and I've moved a trimmed version of your code in a snippet. This should make it a bit more accessible to people looking for the same answer.

Answer (score 4):

In one of my projects we used something like this

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $state, $location) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams,
    fromState) {
    $state.previous = fromState;
  });
```

to remember the previous state. But you might as well remember the new state and store the information somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

You already know which state it will be, because you define it in the `.state('statename',`. To not write the same name twice, you can define the state variables beforehand:

```
var steps = ["step1", "step2", "step3"]; // or, something like Steps.getSteps()

$stateProvider
    .state(steps[0], {
        url: '/step1',
        templateUrl: 'templates/step1.html',
        controller: 'StepOneController',
        onEnter: function(Steps) {
            var stateName = steps[0];
            var step = Steps.getByStateName(stateName);

            step.activate();
        },
        onExit: function($state, Steps) {
            var stateName = $state.current.name; // No problem. We know about the state. 
            var step = Steps.getByStateName(stateName);
            step.deactivate();
        }
    });
```

You can even make it dynamic this way:

```
var steps = [
    { name: "step1", url: "/step1" },
    { name: "step2", url: "/step2" },
    { name: "step3", url: "/step3" }
]; // Or something like Steps.getSteps();

for (var i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {
    var state = steps[i];
    $stateProvider.state(state.name,
        url: state.url,
        templateUrl: "templates/" + state.name + ".html",
        onEnter: function(Steps) {
            var step = Steps.getByStateName(state.name);
            step.activate();

            // or just: state.activate();
        },
        onExit: function($state, Steps) {
            var stateName = $state.current.name; // No problem. We know about the state. 
            var step = Steps.getByStateName(stateName);

            step.deactivate();
        }
}
```

Comment: This wont work for me for various reasons. The 1st options is actually not significantly smaller, but a lot less readable once more routes are introduced. The 2nd one because I still need fine-grained control over some edge cases. What I need is a way to pass a re-usable function into the `onEnter` and `onExit` hooks. I'm currently using a factory function for the `onEnter` hook, which works, but it isn't an ideal solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could extend your factory solution a little bit and make it more flexible.

Maybe have a `provider` that reacts to the state changes.
Then you could just inject this provider/service to `onEnter` function or where-ever you may need it.

Related plunker here http://plnkr.co/edit/6Ri2hE

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.router'])
  .provider('myState', function myStateProvider() {
    var state;

    this.onEnter = function() {
      console.log('provider.onEnter', state);
    };

    this.$get = function($rootScope) {
      var myState = {};

      myState.initialize = function() {
        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
          state = toState;
        });
      };

      myState.getState = function() {
        return state;
      };

      return myState;      
    };
  }) 

  .config(function($stateProvider, myStateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('step1', {
        url: '/step1',
        template: '<div>step1 template</div>',
        controller: function() {},
        onEnter: myStateProvider.onEnter  // usage example
      })
      .state('step2', {
        url: '/step2',
        template: '<div>step2 template</div>',
        controller: function() {},
        onEnter: function(myState) {     // other usage example 
          console.log('state.onEnter', myState.getState());
        }
      });
  })

  .run(function(myState) {
    myState.initialize();
  });
```

---

```
<a ui-sref="step1">state:step1</a>
<a ui-sref="step2">state:step2</a>
<div ui-view></div>
```

This would `console.log()` the following, if links are clicked sequentially.

[image: imgur]

Answer (score 1):

Add a 'name' property naming the state:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('step1', {
    name: 'step1' // <- property naming the state
    url: '/step1',
    templateUrl: 'templates/step1.html',
    controller: 'StepOneController',
    onEnter: onEnter
  });
```

The route's name is then accessible by `this.name` in the `onEnter` callback:

```
function onEnter() {
  var stateName = this.name; // <- Retrieve the state's name from its configuration
  var step = Steps.getByStateName(stateName);
  step.activate();
}
```

To not write the same state name twice, you could start by defining the states in a separate object and enriching the states with their name before adding them to the `$stateProvider`:

```
var routes = {
  "step1": {
    url: '/step1',
    templateUrl: 'templates/step1.html',
    controller: 'StepOneController',
    onEnter: onEnter
  }
};

for(var routeName in routes) {
      var route = routes[routeName];
      // Enrich route with its name before feeding 
      // it to the $stateProvider
      route.name = routeName;
      $stateProvider.state(route.name, route);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use resolve,

```
$stateProvider
  .state('step1', {
   url: '/step1',
   templateUrl: 'templates/step1.html',
   controller: 'StepOneController',
   resolve: {
       onenter : function( Steps ) {
          // use this.self.name to access state name
          var step = Steps.getByStateName(this.self.name);
          step.activate();
       }
   } 
} );
```

If the above `this` approach seems unclean then maybe one can use decorator to populate current state.

```
angular.config(function($provide) {
  $provide.decorator('$state', function($delegate, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, state) {
      $delegate.next = state;
    });
    return $delegate;
  });
});
```

State will be available in `$state.next` inside resolve function.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a try. Seems to me the that the `$state.next` should also be available in the `onEnter` hook, maybe I should contact the developers about this.